# Maximum Likelihood Estimation (log-likelihood) Mistake search

Tags: maximum-likelihood, likelihood

I wanted to ask if my way was right because the end function looks quite complicated:

iid X1, ... , Xn with f(x) = 1/2σ * exp(−|x|/σ),  x∈R, σ > 0 with σ being our searched parameter.

My try:

L(σ)
<=> ∏ (i=1 and top is n)  = 1/2σ * exp (-|x|/σ)

now log-likelihood:

<=> [image] * [image]

<=> [image: log(1/2σ^n * exp(-|x|/σ^n))]       => log(1/2σ^n) + log(exp(-|x|/σ^n))

<=> log(1) - log(2σ^n) + (-|x|/σ^n)

<=> -n log(2σ) + (-|x|/σ^n)

now the derivate l'(σ)

<=> -n/σ + (-n|x|*σ^(-n-1))
 != 0

At this point I wouldn't know what to do (it's too complicated for our class)? I think I made a mistake before but I can't see it.

Comment: Your " log(exp(-|x|/σ^n))" is the most significant of your errors

Comment: Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for typesetting and add the `self-study` tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you have a Laplace distribution with mean $0$.  This is not difficult.

The likelihood is $$\prod \frac{1}{2\sigma} e^{-|x_i|/\sigma} = \frac{1}{2^n\sigma^n} e^{-\sum |x_i| /\sigma} $$

and the log-likelihood is $$-n \log_e(2) - n \log_e(\sigma) - \frac{\sum |x_i|}{\sigma} $$

and the derivative of the log-likelihood with respect to $\sigma$ is $$-\frac{n}{\sigma} +   \frac{\sum |x_i|}{\sigma^2}$$

which is zero when $$\sigma = \frac{\sum |x_i|}{n} = \overline{|x_i|}$$

Comment: thank you very much! It looks way simpler now, I though x was just a constant, wish it was xi in the task!